# Represent a boolean value in Primefaces DataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, boolean

So I am attempting to pass object values from a bean into a primefaces datatable (using primefaces 3.4 currently), howevever I'm facing two problems with this.

**1.** I cannot seem to find any way to display (or represent) a boolean value within a column in a datatable. Every time I attempt this, the table returns back totally empty (even though without the boolean column the other columns are populated with data from the bean).

**2.** The other bigger problem (more to do with java I think than primefaces) is that I have currently 26 different Objects I get from Siebels CRM ONDemand cloud solution, each containing their own datatypes and attribute values. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to, based on a drop down selection of a specific object display that objects fields dynamically within a primefaces datatable. So far I have just managed to display some of the fields for 1 of these objects as a sort of prototype but I am having the problem with the boolean value being display also its a nightmare.

Anybody have any sort of similar experiences ? or suggestions? I've been puzzled by this for over 2 weeks now and I am going absolutely crazy!

I can provide code examples or other details if needed :)

**Thanks a lot I really appreciate any help !**

Reggie

Html code:

```xml
<p:panel header ="Source Environment" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
    <p:dataTable draggableColumns="true" id="tableFieldSet1" value="#{ODComBean.fields}" var="tableFieldSet1" rowKey="#{ODComBean.fields}" selectionMode ="multiple" style="font-family:sans-serif; width:max-content;">
        <p:panel header="OD Object Selection" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                <p:selectOneMenu immediate ="true" id="pickList" value="#{ODComBean.fieldSetData}" effect="fade"  style="font-size: 12px; font-family:sans-serif;" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{ODComBean.fieldSet}"  itemLabel="#{fieldSet.objectName}" var="fieldSet"/>
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="@form" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel> 
        <p:panel header ="Source Environment" style="margin-bottom:5px;">          
            <p:dataTable draggableColumns="true" id="tableFieldSet1" value="#{ODComBean.fields}" var="tableFieldSet1" rowKey="#{ODComBean.fields}" selectionMode ="multiple" style="font-family:sans-serif; width:max-content;">     
                 <p:column headerText="Type"  styleClass="singleLine" style="height: 10px; font-size: 8pt;"> 
                     <h:outputText value="#{tableFieldSet1.fieldType}"/>
                 </p:column>
                  <p:column headerText="Required">
                         <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/tick.png" rendered="#{tableFieldSet1.readOnly}"/>
                         <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/red-cross.png" rendered="#{not tableFieldSet1.readOnly}"/>
                 </p:column>
                 <p:column headerText="Name"  styleClass="singleLine" style="height: 10px; font-size: 8pt;">
                     <h:outputText value="#{tableFieldSet1.name}"/>
                 </p:column>
                 <p:column headerText ="Display Name" styleClass="singleLine" style="height: 10px; font-size: 8pt;">
                     <h:outputText value="#{tableFieldSet1.displayName}"/>
                 </p:column>
                 <p:column headerText="Default Value"   styleClass="singleLine" style="height: 10px; font-size: 8pt;">
                     <h:outputText value="#{tableFieldSet1.defaultValue}"/>
                 </p:column>
                 <p:column headerText="Generic Integration Tag" styleClass="singleLine" style="height: 10px; font-size: 8pt;">
                     <h:outputText value="#{tableFieldSet1.genericIntegrationTag}"/>
                 </p:column>
                 <p:column headerText ="Integration Tag"  styleClass="singleLine" style="height: 10px; font-size: 8pt;">
                      <h:outputText value="#{tableFieldSet1.integrationTag}"/>
                 </p:column>
                 <p:column headerText ="Translations" styleClass="singleLine" style="height: 10px; font-size: 8pt;">
                     <h:outputText value="#{tableFieldSet1.listOfFieldTranslations}"/>
                 </p:column>
                 <p:column headerText ="Validation Error"  styleClass="singleLine" style="height: 10px; font-size: 8pt;">
                     <h:outputText value="#{tableFieldSet1.validationErrorMsg}"/>
                 </p:column>
                     <!-- When I add the next Column it will only show data for the first line, and display a <div half tag in the last column... strange... !-->

    </p:dataTable>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: I can't imagine how a boolean property can ever form a problem this way. An [SSCCE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) would be helpful in better understanding the concrete problem.

Comment: Hi Balus, Unfortunately I don't know If I could provide a SSCCE as you would need the WSDL (Web service Description Lanaguage File) which I use to get the objects, Or at least not a compilable one. I could however copy a snippet of my xhtml and the backing bean which are relevant and maybe you can spot some sort of mistake I've made?? If at all possible,, Thanks for response ;)

Comment: If you can't just stub it yourself, then it would most likely not be a JSF specific problem.

Comment: I think it's more I have no idea how to put for example a check box within a column and use a boolean valued variable to define if its ticked or not (true or false). Currently Im trying to display the boolean value within a h:outputText tag which I believe is probably incorrect :/

Comment: Just use `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.property}">` (or `p:`) where `#{item}` is the `<p:dataTable var="item">`?

Comment: Hi again Balus, So I tried that, but to no avail, I tried both h: and p: with selectBooleanCheckbox, and have used the var of the datatable then .property. The table just displays the first row (removing all the others) and in the boolean column it shows a "<div" tag inside?? strange or what?

Comment: Seems like an exception was thrown in midst of rendering, probably due to a syntax error or incomplete code in the markup. Have you for instance looked at the server logs? The exception should be logged there. Otherwise increase response buffer size by `javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE` context param so that the exception will be shown in its entirety in an error page.

Comment: it's completely beyond me how the currently accepted answer was helpful in solving your concrete problem. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Well It didn't solve my problem yet, but it's a great solution for representing  a boolean value in a data table in general (As the title says) - so I felt it was worthy of acknowledgement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to use a h:outputText, you can set its converter to something that you implemented and inside that converter, decide about the display value.
Otherwise, if you like to view an icon according to the value, 
you can do like this :

```
<p:column headerText="My Boolean Value">
   <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/tick.png" rendered="#{MODEL.boolean}"/>
   <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/red-cross.png"  rendered="#{not MODEL.boolean}"/>
</p:column>
```

I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: I appreciate the answer Hossein, I will implement this now and see how it works! Thanks again m8

Comment: Hi Hossein, I tried to implement this solution, and I am sure that it would work but I keep getting a strange occurance where when I put any column which uses my boolean value from the bean. The table will display correctly up until the first occurance of a boolean representation and instead display a "<div " like that in the column. I'm bewildered :D Have you ever seen this kind of thing?

Comment: Hi Reggie, I have no idea what is the problem there, I am using the solution I.ve told you alot in my project, and I have no problem at all! Can you send your code? that may helps to identify the problem

Comment: For some reason stack over flow makes it super complicated to copy code in and post it. So if you have somewhere I can send it or some place you would like it uploaded I could do that :D Takes a rocket scientist to figure out the syntax required to post on this form...

Comment: you can mail it to me, hossein.arbaboon@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Reggie, I've sent you an email with my opinion. take a look and let me know the result :)

Comment: So it turns out that within my generated classes netbeans created a method called "isRequired()" which returned the boolean value. However JSF does not recognise this and so I changed the isRequired() to getRequired() and the boolean values where correctly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

[Output panel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/outputPanel.xhtml) with *layout* set to *inline* produce a *<span>* tag with the style class you provide.

You can for example use the [*jquery-ui* icons](http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/) provided by the framework. Like this:

```
<p:outputPanel layout="inline" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" rendered="#{project.inBudget}" />
<p:outputPanel layout="inline" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close" rendered="#{!project.inBudget}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a **check mark** symbol for `true` and **empty String**, or **x** symbol for `false`.

```
<p:column headerText="Required" style="text-align: center">
    <h:outputText value="#{tableFieldSet1.readOnly ? '✓' : ''}"/>
</p:column>
```